# Existing windows application to intel appup

Tags: c#, winapi

Intel has provided one SDK for developing and submitting applications to intel appup.

It is mentioned that C/C++ Win32 applications are supported in it. Is there any way to submit the existing C# Win32 application to appup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/article/faq#dev_00) says

> **What runtimes or technologies are currently supported?**
>   Moblin* Native, and Windows* Native

C# is not native code, it is managed code on .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this was posted, but the SDK now supports C, C++, .NET, Java, Adobe Air and MeeGo.